# Time complexity of determining if two binary trees are swap-equivalent

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, graph-theory

I have solved [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/flip-equivalent-binary-trees/) problem about determining if two binary trees are equal with the code snippet from below.

The problem is as follows:

> For a binary tree T, we can define a flip operation as follows: choose any > node, and swap the left and right child subtrees.
>
> A binary tree X is flip equivalent to a binary tree Y if and only if
> we can make X equal to Y after some number of flip operations.
>
> Given the roots of two binary trees root1 and root2, return true if
> the two trees are flip equivelent or false otherwise.

My reasoning is that the growth function is T(n)=4(T(n-1)) one for each of the four recursive calls where n is the height of the largest tree. I would then expect this to have a time complexity of O(4^n) but this does not match up with the reasoning in the solution which says that the time complexity is O(max(N_1,N_2)).

What is flawed in this reasoning of being O(4^n) given that the solution has a different time complexity?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean flipEquiv(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        if (root1 == root2)
            return true;
        if (root1 == null || root2 == null || root1.val != root2.val)
            return false;

        return (flipEquiv(root1.left, root2.left) && flipEquiv(root1.right, root2.right) ||
                flipEquiv(root1.left, root2.right) && flipEquiv(root1.right, root2.left));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question clearly? I dont get what is incorrect here or what you are expecting exactly

Comment: The problem statements says that the nodes in each tree have *unique values*, so at least 2 of the 4 recursive calls will return immediately.

Comment: You are going down from the root at each step and verifying if they are either equal or not? If they are we can move ahead, if not, we can swap them, check again, if they are equal now, we can move ahead or simply return false if they are not (so, we visit each node not more than twice). Nevertheless, we are going down the tree at each step and hence, the complexity is O(min(N_1, N_2). And I think it should be O of min and not max.